# Pyspark flatten RDD error:: Too many values to unpack

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm trying to flatten data in an RDD. The RDD is structured as a list of 4-tuples with the first element - primary_id ,  the second element - a list of dictionaries, third and fourth elements each contain a single list containing a dictionary.

```
rdd=   [('xxxxx99', [{'cov_id':'Q', 'cov_cd':'100','cov_amt':'100', 'cov_state':'AZ'},
                  {'cov_id':'Q', 'cov_cd':'33','cov_amt':'200', 'cov_state':'AZ'},
                  {'cov_id':'Q', 'cov_cd':'64','cov_amt':'10', 'cov_state':'AZ'}],
                  [{'pol_cat_id':'234','pol_dt':'20100220'}],
                  [{'qor_pol_id':'23492','qor_cd':'30'}]),

     ('xxxxx86', [{'cov_id':'R', 'cov_cd':'20','cov_amt':'100', 'cov_state':'TX'},
                  {'cov_id':'R', 'cov_cd':'44','cov_amt':'500', 'cov_state':'TX'},
                  {'cov_id':'R', 'cov_cd':'66','cov_amt':'50', 'cov_state':'TX'}],
                  [{'pol_cat_id':'532','pol_dt':'20091020'}],
                  [{'qor_pol_id':'49320','qor_cd':'21'}]) ]
```

I want to flatten the data so that it appears in the format

[image]

how would I do this in Pyspark?

Here is what I have attempted but this gives me an error: Too many tuples to unpack

```
def flatten_map(record):
    try:
        yield(record)
        # Unpack items
        id, items, line, pls = record
        pol_id = pls["pol_cat_id"]
        pol_dt = pls["pol_dt"]
        qor_id = pls["qor_pol_id"]
        for item in items:
            yield (id,item["cov_id"],item["cov_cd"], item["cov_amt"], item["cov_state"], pol_id, pol_dt, qor_id), 1
    except Exception as e:
        pass

 result = (rdd
    # Expand data
    .flatMap(flatten_map)
    # Flatten tuples
    .map(lambda x: x[0], ))
```

I can post the complete error if required but for sake of brevity,

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Note: converting to pandas doesn't work as RDD is too big

Comment: fixed it...that's not causing the error though

Comment: @jxc done. would you mind upvoting my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can run flatMap() by using a list comprehension to iterate through the 2nd item of the 4-item tuples(1 string + 3 lists), for example:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

myrdd = sc.parallelize(rdd)

myrdd.flatMap(lambda x: [ ({'primary_id':x[0]}, z, x[2][0], x[3][0]) for z in x[1] ] ).collect()
#[({'primary_id': 'xxxxx99'},
#  {'cov_id': 'Q', 'cov_cd': '100', 'cov_amt': '100', 'cov_state': 'AZ'},
#  {'pol_cat_id': '234', 'pol_dt': '20100220'},
#  {'qor_pol_id': '23492', 'qor_cd': '30'}),
# ......
```

**Short explanation:** in the list comprehension of flatMap function, besides iterating the 2nd item `x[1]` (as `z` which is a dictionary), I also converted the first String item *x[0]* into a dictionary with one entry: `{"primary_id":x[0]}` and take the first item of *x[2]* and *x[3]*, both of which are dictionaries.

Thus after running the above flatMap function, the RDD element becomes a tuple of 4 dictionaries, what you need to do next is just to merge them. below is my sample-code to map the tuple of 4-dictionaries into Row object, you might have to change the logic how to handle exceptions and missing fields to fit your own requirements.

```
cols = ['primary_id', 'cov_id', 'cov_cd', 'cov_amt', 'cov_state', 'pol_cat_id', 'pol_dt', 'qor_pol_id', 'qor_cd']

def merge_dict(arr, cols):
  row = {}
  try:
    for e in arr:
      if type(e) is dict: row.update(e)
  except:
    pass
  finally:
    return Row(**dict({ c:row.get(c, None) for c in cols })) if row else None

myrdd.flatMap(lambda x: [ ({'primary_id':x[0]}, z, x[2][0], x[3][0]) for z in x[1] ] ) \
   .map(lambda x: merge_dict(x, cols)) \
   .filter(bool) \
   .toDF() \
   .show()
+-------+------+------+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+----------+
|cov_amt|cov_cd|cov_id|cov_state|pol_cat_id|  pol_dt|primary_id|qor_cd|qor_pol_id|
+-------+------+------+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+----------+
|    100|   100|     Q|       AZ|       234|20100220|   xxxxx99|    30|     23492|
|    200|    33|     Q|       AZ|       234|20100220|   xxxxx99|    30|     23492|
|     10|    64|     Q|       AZ|       234|20100220|   xxxxx99|    30|     23492|
|    100|    20|     R|       TX|       532|20091020|   xxxxx86|    21|     49320|
|    500|    44|     R|       TX|       532|20091020|   xxxxx86|    21|     49320|
|     50|    66|     R|       TX|       532|20091020|   xxxxx86|    21|     49320|
+-------+------+------+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+----------+
```

**BTW.** if you want to make your original function work, check the following 5 lines containing **`#<--`**:

```
def flatten_map(record): 
  try: 
    #yield(record)    #<-- comment this out, no need unprocessed data in output
    # Unpack items 
    id, items, line, pls = record 
    pol_id = line[0]["pol_cat_id"]      #<-- from line[0] not pls
    pol_dt = line[0]["pol_dt"]          #<-- from line[0] not pls
    qor_id = pls[0]["qor_pol_id"]       #<-- from pls[0] not pls
    for item in items: 
      #<-- below line removed the ending ", 1", thus no need the last map() function to flatten tuples
      yield (id,item["cov_id"],item["cov_cd"], item["cov_amt"], item["cov_state"], pol_id, pol_dt, qor_id)
  except Exception as e: 
    pass
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. this helped me a lot.